# what process is preventing my file from getting deleted in C#

Tags: c#

I have a C# single thread application that creates a file. Uses that file and then deletes it. Some times the app has trouble deleting that file. The error I get is:

"The process cannot access the file --file path and file name-- because it is being used by another process."

How can I find out what process has a hold on this file and how can I make that process to let go so that the file can be deleted.

Comment: Share the code you use to access it during the lifetime of your application and I bet you find out "who's using" the file.

Comment: You probably never close the file - you need to close it before you can delete it if you have opened it yourself.

Comment: Could maybe be the windows indexing service. There's a free utility called WhoLockMe that I've used successfully in the past. (Google it)

Comment: Hope you didn't locked by yourself ...

Comment: @JC. Another tool you might enjoy is [Unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/)

Comment: Do you have a virus checker running?  Virus checkers are notorious for causing this sort of problem. The scenario is: you close the file, the virus checker says "aha, someone just closed a file, now is my chance to see if it has a virus", and while it is checking, the file cannot be deleted. These problems are hard to diagnose if you don't know what to look for.

Answer (score 0):

This thing rocks for that very "gotcha".

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx

Process Monitor v3.05

It has a "Filter" submenu so you can fine tune it to the file that is locked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to post the relevant code so we can see.

It is however always important to make sure that your app close the file that it has opened.

usually something like this will ensure that:

```
    using(var f = File.OpenRead("myfile")) {

       ...
    }
```

or the equivalent:

```
    try {
       var f = File.OpenRead("myfile");
    } finally {

       f.close()

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are closing file before delete.

if you are using StreamWriter class make sure that you are closing with its variable

```
Ex. StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter();
     // some writing operation 
    sw.Close();
```

Comment: Thank you ALL for your comments and suggestions. I had to force garbage collection in my finally block. And that released all the file stream resources.